Двусвязный циклический список. Не могу переделать из функционального в ООП стиль
Написал двусвязный циклический список с "барьерным" элементом. Требуется переделать в ООП стиль. Появились проблемы с доступом к данным. Также я не уверен, что делаю без "костылей". Мои мысли: правильно ли, что я разделил на два класса (1 - одна запись с функциями без управления памятью, 2 - барьерный элемент, функции управления памятью)?; как сделать так, чтобы не использовать гетеры и сетеры?; Можно закинуть в паблик, но тогда пользователь может изменять данные сам; нет ли у меня утечки памяти?. Прошу помочь!
Вот мой код в функциональном виде:
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node;
void print(Node *list);
void print_back(Node *list);
void print_dbg(Node *list);
void insert(Node *p, Node *t);
void insert_before(Node *q, Node *t);
void init(Node *list);

void list_remove(Node *t);
bool list_empty(Node *list);
Node* push_front(Node *list, int d);
Node * push_back(Node *list, int d);
int list_delete(Node *t);
int pop_front(Node *list);
int pop_back(Node *list);
void clear(Node *list);

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *prev;
    struct Node *next;
};

void print(Node *list) {
    for (Node *p = list->next; p != list ;p=p->next) {
        cout << p->data << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void print_back(Node *list) {
    for (Node *p = list->prev; p != list ;p=p->prev) {
        cout << p->data << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n---------------" << endl;
}

void print_dbg(Node *list) {
    Node *p = list;
    cout << "list: prev=" << p->prev << " " << p << " next=" << p->next << endl;
    for (p = list->prev; p != list ;p=p->prev) {
        cout << p->data << " prev=" << p->prev << " " << p << " next=" << p->next << endl;
    }
}

void insert(Node *p, Node *t) {
    Node *q = p->next;
    t->prev = p;
    t->next = q;
    p->next = t;
    q->prev = t;
}

void insert_before(Node *q, Node *t) {
    insert(q->prev, t);
}

void init(Node *list) {
    list->prev = list;
    list->next = list;
}

void list_remove(Node *t) {
    t->prev->next = t->next;
    t->next->prev = t->prev;
}

bool list_empty(Node *list) {
    return (list->prev == list && list->next == list);
}

Node* push_front(Node *list, int d) {
    Node *pr = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    pr->data = d;
    insert(list, pr);
    return pr;
}

Node * push_back(Node *list, int d) {
    return push_front(list->prev, d);
}

int list_delete(Node *t) {
    list_remove(t);
    int d = t->data;
    free(t);
    return d;
}

int pop_front(Node *list) {
    return list_delete(list->next);
}

int pop_back(Node *list) {
    return list_delete(list->prev);
}

void clear(Node *list) {
    while (!list_empty(list)) {
        pop_front(list);
    }
}

void test_alloc() {
    Node z{};
    Node *list = &z;

    int test_data1[] = {21, 17, 3};
    int test_data2[] = {10, 8};

    init(list);
    cout << "Empty ";
    list_empty(list) ? cout << "YES" << endl : cout << "NO" << endl;

    Node *t;
    for (auto x : test_data1) {
        t = push_front(list, x);
        print(list);
        cout << "pushed: " << t->data << endl;
    } // 3 17 21
    for (auto x : test_data2) {
        t = push_back(list, x);
        print(list);
        cout << "pushed: " << t->data << endl;
    } // 3 17 21 10 8

    cout << "Empty ";
    list_empty(list) ? cout << "YES" << endl : cout << "NO" << endl;
    t = list->next->next; // 17
    int res;

    res = list_delete(t);
    print(list); // 3 21 10 8
    cout << "deleted: " << res << endl; // 17

    res = pop_front(list);
    print(list); // 21 10 8
    cout << "pop front: " << res << endl; // 3

    res = pop_back(list);
    print(list); // 21 10
    cout << "pop back: " << res << endl; // 8

    clear(list);
    cout << "Empty ";
    list_empty(list) ? cout << "YES" << endl : cout << "NO" << endl;
}

void test() {
    Node z{}, a{}, b{}, c{}, u{}, w{};
    a.data = 3;
    b.data = 17;
    c.data = 21;
    u.data = 10;
    w.data = 8;
    Node *list = &z;
    init(list);
    list_empty(list)? cout << "YES" << endl : cout << "NO" << endl; //YES

    insert(list, &c);
    list_empty(list)? cout << "YES" << endl : cout << "NO" << endl; //NO
    print(list); // 21

    insert(list, &b);
    print(list); // 17 21

    insert(list, &a);
    print(list); // 3 17 21

    print(list); //3 17 21
    print_back(list); // 21 17 3
    print_dbg(list);

    insert(&a, &u);
    print(list); //3 10 17 21
    print_back(list); // 21 17 10 3

    insert_before(&u, &w);
    print(list); //3 8 10 17 21
    print_back(list); // 21 17 10 8 3

    list_remove(&u);
    print(list); //3 8 17 21
    print_back(list); // 21 17 8 3

    list_remove(&w);
    print(list); //3 17 21
    print_back(list); // 21 17 3
}

int main() {
    // test();
    test_alloc();

    return 0;
}

Вот до чего я дошёл в ООП стиле:
-----
Node.h
-----
class Node {
protected:
    Node *prev;
    int data;
    Node *next;
public:
    Node(): data{0}, prev{nullptr}, next{nullptr} {};
    explicit Node(int d): data{d}, prev{nullptr}, next{nullptr} {};

    [[nodiscard]] int GetData() const;
    void setData(int a) {data = a;}
    virtual void print(Node *list);
    virtual void print_back(Node *list);
    virtual void insert(Node *p, Node *t);
    virtual void insert_before(Node *q, Node *t);
    virtual void init(Node *list);
    virtual void list_remove(Node *t);
    virtual bool list_empty(Node *list);
};

-----
NodesList.h
-----
#include "Node.h"

class NodesList : public Node {
private:
    Node z{};
    Node *list = &z;
public:
    NodesList* push_front(int d) {
        Node *pr = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        pr->setData(d);
        insert(this->list, pr);
        return this;
    }

    NodesList* push_back(int d) {
        Node *pr = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        pr->setData(d);
        insert_before(this->list, pr);
        return this;
    }

    NodesList() {
        Node::init(this->list);
    }

    explicit NodesList(int a) {
        Node::init(this->list);
        push_front(a);
    }

    void print() {
        Node::print(this->list);
    }

    int list_delete(Node *t) {
        list_remove(t);
        int d = t->GetData();
        free(t);
        return d;
    }

    int pop_front() {
        return list_delete(list->next);
    }

    int pop_back(Node *list) {
        return list_delete(list->prev);
    }

    void clear(Node *list) {
        while (!list_empty(list)) {
            pop_front(list);
        }
    }
};


Первое - это не функциональный, а процедурный стиль. Ну а второе практически не отличается от первого, ведь там по сути только обернуто в class. Даже сигнатуры методов скопипасчены, хотя они все должны были поменяться, ведь this передается неявно.

А вот это, как серьезные люди работают с подобными списками

@avp Ну так это от отсутствия ++, в противном случае не выделывались бы.

@0andriy, боюсь вы не поняли сути того подхода. Он позволяет одним и тем же данным одновременно находиться в нескольких списках. А что для этого могут предложить кресты? Множественное наследование?

@avp, боюсь это вы не поняли изначальной идеи (в проекте Linux kernel).

Класс узла Node переусложнен. Ему вообще лучше быть тривиальным.
Переусложненное наследование, классическая путаница между is-a и has-a.  Список функционально не является узлом, поэтому не является потомком узла, он является  контейнером для того что хранится в узле, а узел - либо внутренний класс, либо интерфейс для "итератора".
И все в итоге можно превратить в шаблон где Т вместо int.
Строго говоря простейший список с барьерным элементом не является циклическим, это вариант двухсвязного списка. Барьерный элемент - фиктивен и перейти  от последнего к первому нельзя, как и "разыменовать" его. Зато у нас есть метки начала и конца. Простейший пример:
#include <iostream>

class NodeList {
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        friend NodeList;
        using  value_type = int;

        Node() = default;
        Node(const Node&) = default;
        Node(Node&&) = default;
        Node& operator=(const Node&) = default;
        Node& operator=(Node&&) = default;

        bool operator !=(const Node& o) const 
        { return std::tie(next, prev) != std::tie(o.next,o.prev); }
        bool operator ==(const Node& o) const 
        { return std::tie(next, prev) == std::tie(o.next,o.prev); }

        [[nodiscard]] value_type operator*() { return *value; }
        Node operator++(int) { if(!next) throw; Node n = *this; *this = *next; return n; }
        Node operator--(int) { if(!prev) throw; Node n = *this; *this = *prev; return n; }

        Node& operator++() { if(!next) throw; return *this = *next; }
        Node& operator--() { if(!prev) throw; return *this = *prev; }
    private:
        Node *next,   *prev;
        value_type*   value; 

        Node(Node * p, Node * n, value_type* v) : next(n), prev(p), value(v) {
            p->next = this; n->prev = this;
        }
    };

    Node z = { &z, &z, nullptr };
    Node * root = &z;
public:
    using value_type = Node::value_type;
    using iterator = Node;

    iterator begin() { if(!z.next) throw; return *(z.next); }
    iterator end() { return z; }

    iterator push_back(value_type v) {
        iterator *node = new iterator(z.prev, &z, new value_type(v));
        return *node;
    }

    iterator push_front(value_type v) {
        iterator *node = new iterator(&z, z.next, new value_type(v));
        return *node;
    }
};

int main()
{
    NodeList r;

    r.push_back(3);
    r.push_front(2);
    r.push_front(1);
    for(int i : r) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}

Тут нужно что-то делать по поводу фрагментации памяти и поддержки аллокаторов. Интерфейс итератора лучше отделить от узла и в нем хранить только указатель на  узел. Таким образом не будем копировать весь узел.
